# GdiPlus::DrawImage stretches image after I have edited it with GIMP?

Tags: png, gdi+, gimp

I use this code to draw a png into my device context:

```
auto_ptr<Gdiplus::Graphics> g(Gdiplus::Graphics::FromHDC(pDC->GetSafeHdc()));
g->DrawImage(pPng, xDest, yDest, xSrc, ySrc, nSrcWidth, pSrcHeight, Gdiplus::UnitPixel);
```

This pastes the png just how it's supposed to. I edit the png with GIMP. My function now draws the png **stretched**. I edit it with mspaint doing the exact same changes. The png is drawn fine.

How does this happen?

Comment: Can you upload an example image somewhere?

Comment: check that you are not changing the DPI when you save from GIMP.  in general you should account for it in your code to "counter-scale" against the DPI of your device context.  for example there would be a difference between screen and print device contexts, and on printer your image would become tiny tiny.

Comment: I had forgotten about this question. The problem was with the DPI, it was set to something else by GIMP. I fixed the problem by using the GDIPlus function that specifies destination width and height.